# Import salem leads to ERROR 1 "libgrass_dgl" and "libgrass_vector": cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python-3.x, geospatial, ubuntu-18.04

**Python version:**

Python 3.8.5 (default, Jul 22 2020, 18:54:26)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux

**OS:**

Linux Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

**Error description:**

Upon importing the package [salem](https://github.com/fmaussion/salem) the following error occurs:

```
In: import salem

Out:
ERROR 1: libgrass_dgl.7.4.0.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
ERROR 1: libgrass_dgl.7.4.0.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
ERROR 1: libgrass_vector.7.4.0.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
ERROR 1: libgrass_vector.7.4.0.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/257244/155426).

In my case, the correct command was precisely:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/grass74/lib/libgrass_* /usr/lib/
```

Now, `import salem` throws no errors and functions just normally.